# Error when try to read from a QFile

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to read some data from a file with QT and then show data in a QTableWidget through a QComboBox.

```
void DemoDataView::on_comboBox_activated(const QString &arg1)
{
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(21);
    ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Age Range ; Male Population ; Male Percentage ; Female Population ; Female Percentage").split(";"));
    ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->tableWidget->resizeRowsToContents();

QFile inputFile("./data.txt");

if(!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", inputFile.errorString());
}

QTextStream in(&inputFile);
int rows = 0;

while(!in.atEnd()) {

    QString mLine = in.readLine();
    QStringList fields = mLine.split(" ");
    QStringList::iterator it = fields.begin();
    QString regName = *it;

    ui->label->setText(arg1);

    if(regName != "<END>" && QString::compare(regName, arg1) == 0) {
        ui->label->setText(regName);
        it++;
        QString ageRange = *it;
        it++;
        QString nMale = *it;
        double male = nMale.toDouble();
        it++;
        QString nFemale = *it;
        double female = nFemale.toDouble();
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(rows, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(ageRange));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(rows, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(nMale));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(rows, 3, new QTableWidgetItem(nFemale));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(rows, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(malePercCalc(male, female)));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(rows, 4, new QTableWidgetItem(femalePercCalc(male, female)));

        rows++;

    }

inputFile.close();

    }
}
```

The file is in both the project folder and the build project folder.
When I run the application everything works good but in the Application Output tab I have this error message:

"QIODevice:: read (QFile, "./data.txt"): device not open"

Every time I click on a QComboBox item.

If it can be useful, this is the filling code of the QComboBox:

```
void DemoDataView::setComboBoxRegion() {

QFile inputFile("./data.txt");

if(!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", inputFile.errorString());
}

QTextStream in(&inputFile);

while(!in.atEnd()) {

    QString mLine = in.readLine();
    QStringList fields = mLine.split(" ");


    QStringList::iterator it = fields.begin();
    QString regName = *it;

    if(regName != "<END>") {
        if(ui->comboBox->findText(regName) == -1){
            ui->comboBox->addItem(regName);
        }
    }
}

inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: "./data.txt" this path is correct? where are you have data.txt?

Comment: I'd suggest using full paths like `QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/data.txt`

Comment: As i said in the post above the file is saved in both the project folder and the build project folder.

I assume it is right cause i can see data in my QTableWidget

I tried with 
' QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/data.txt" ' 
but i have the same problem

Comment: stupid idea - maybe you are trying to read from the same file somwhere else in your code and you forget to open file there? because this code looks fine and you will get an error message if file is not open

Comment: Maybe problem is that you call `inputFile.close();` in while loop, where you read data in this loop using `in.readLine();`.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks so much, the problem was just that! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add tags to your question title, including `[solved]` tags, as it may be perceived as unneeded noise by the community. When an answer is accepted, this is an acceptable way to show that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling:

```
inputFile.close();
```

INSIDE of your loop, which means it is closed in the first loop. I can't really think of any cases that this would be the desired thing to happen;

To solve this, you should move it to the *outside* of the loop.